# mysql if statement rows check

Tags: mysql, if-statement

```
SELECT s.srv_id, sp.is_nocommission 
FROM services_param sp
JOIN services s ON (sp.pid = s.id) 
WHERE sp.prefix LIKE '%011%';
```

I can get one or more results. If `srv_id` has `is_nocommission` set to 1 (not null), I need to select only it, either way I need to select the least.
Please help.

Comment: How can you associate a value to a field of a field?

Comment: Do you mean that you need to have the row with the minimum sp.is_nocomission value?

Comment: No, minimum srv_id value, but it is not the case

Answer (score 0):

Although I am not fully clear enough about your question and comments, but you may try the following:

```
SELECT CASE sp.is_nocommission WHEN 1 THEN s.srv_id ELSE MIN(s.srv_id) END
FROM services_param sp
JOIN services s ON (sp.pid = s.id) 
WHERE sp.prefix LIKE '%011%'
```